# I deleted some files from my computer and now I can't run a script/program. What do I do?

Tags: python

I recently permanently deleted some files from computer. Now I can't run a script/program.

When I open an new terminal at the folder, I get this message...

```
Last login: Mon Oct 26 07:56:13 on ttys005
Vanessa-Chiangs-MacBook-Air:GTIM 0.8.2 vcchiang$ python3 GTIM.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GTIM.py", line 6, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtCore'
Vanessa-Chiangs-MacBook-Air:GTIM 0.8.2 vcchiang$
```

What do I do?

Comment: Did you already try to reinstall python?

Comment: We can glean that you are on a Mac, but you should put details like this in the question.

Comment: It occurs to me this might be better suited to Ask Different SE...

Answer (score 0):

You deleted something that is needed by some Python process invoked from your shell. When you invoke GTIM.py from the Terminal, some import is missing. What appears to be missing is all or parts of [PyQt5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt5).

You need to reinstall the thing that is needed by the shell startup. It looks like it is failing on some Qt Python bindings, which may either be found in core Python or via some separate library (I'm not sure, but a web search should sort that out).

Now, I did a brief search, and it *appears* that Python Qt5 is a separate module. Though my *guess* is that it is **not** part of the full Mac installer for Python, so you might just need to find the right Python Qt4 installer and run that.

However, if you deleted any of the stuff that came with the OS X system for Python 2 (the version that Apple ships) then you might have to restore from backup. It's going to be tricky to sort out what, exactly, you need from a Time Machine backup, but you can always just restore everything the way it was prior to when you mucked about with the system.

At this point you are going to have to do a little research, learn a little, and incrementally move forward until you know what is missing, what version, and how to replace it. We can help, but it is going to take some back and forth.

<strike>*However*, since we see that you are running Python3, which does **not** ship with OS X, you might as well just reinstall Python 3.5.0 [from here](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/). My guess might be wrong, and it might just replace the QtCore Python module that is missing.</strike> It looks like PyQt[4|5] has to be installed separately using a straightforward (but possible confusing, if you have never done it before) installation process.

- https://gist.github.com/guillaumevincent/10983814
- http://robscurity.blogspot.ca/2015/02/installing-pyqt-on-mac-os-x-yosemite.html
- (Using Homebrew and Ruby) http://macappstore.org/pyqt5/

It is possible that this OS X machine has "Fink" or "HomeBrew" or "MacPorts" installed on it, which might make things easier, as in that last link.

**Conclusion**

This is the line we are concerned with:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
```

The `QtCore` Python bindings from the `PyQt5` module are missing, and this Python script is failing.

Since it looks like you may have deleted parts of the PyQt5 python module bindings, you probably need to replace that, using one of the methods above. Either directly, using tools like `sip`, or using a helper like Fink, Homebrew, or MacPorts. It will depend on what is on this machine already (i.e., was PyQt5 installed with Homebrew already? I can't tell you this) and how good you are at figuring out the links I provided.

Your first step should be seeing if any of these commands are found when invoking them at a Terminal:

- `fink`
- `brew`
- `port`

If any of these return anything other than "command not found" (or similar), then you should be able to figure out how to use that command to re-install the PyQt5 Python bindings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Most of that sounds 'foreign' to me as I'm not well-versed with this kind of stuff. Can you help walk me through this a bit more?

Comment: Assuming you want the Python script GTIM.py to work, you will need to figure out how to repair what is missing. Let's start with the GTIM.py script. Edit your question to include the first 10 lines or so of this script.

Comment: Hi jdv, do you mean this?

#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime, json, os, time, urllib.request
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from scripts import CsvGenerator, PriceUpdater, PriceScraper, Utils



# Paths of important data files
dataPath = "data/AllSets-x.json"
mappingPath = "data/SetList.json"
jsonFolderUrl = "http://mtgjson.com/json/"

Comment: You should "edit" your question to put this information in it

Comment: Sorry jdv; not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can [re-edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33346383/edit) your original question, add the text of your script, and then format the text so that it looks like source code. It should look the same as it does in a text editor on your system, so that we both know what line 6 in the error is referring to.